# Shorten the construction

Tags: python, jinja2

The challenge is to reduce the construction and, if possible, speed up the processing of the code.

```
{% for tp1 in test.tab_tp1s %}
    {{ tp1.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% for tp2 in test.tab_tp2s %}
    {{ tp2.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% for tp3 in test.tab_tp3s %}
    {{ tp3.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is very vague. Probably might want to provide as much detail as possible before this gets deleted.

Comment: This is a working code. Can I write the same thing, but briefly with Jinja?

Comment: Well tab_tp1s, tab_tp2s, and tab_tp3s all come from test, so just loop over test first

Comment: @Ajx I suggest trying this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com (may be a good fit there)

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for tab in test %}
    {% for tp in test[tab]
        {{ tp.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe, it's hard to tell because we don't know what is stored in `test`, I'm assuming test is a dictionary holding 3 keys which each hold a sub key called name?

Comment: The fact is that we have more than one "test".
We have:
    test.tab_tp1s
    test.tab_tp2s
    test.tab_tp3s

Different data in each section